# Android: JSON to DynamoDB

Tags: android, json, amazon-dynamodb

My app conducts a 20-question survey for users and collects their responses in a JSON. I've saved items to DynamoDB from the app before, creating a
[data model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-nosql-database.html#add-aws-mobile-nosql-database-crud-create) as they describe. Do I have to create a data model to upload the answers from this JSON? It seems like a hassle to create a data model of ~20 fields. Is there an easier way to get this JSON from the user's phone to a DynamoDB table holding all of the users' responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB has a map type. Put the JSON response in there.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes